# Create a single array from returned strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a for loop that goes through all elements of a certain class and returns the value (which in my case it's a date — e.g. 2020-05-15) and splits it. So I get multiple arrays from which I want to create one joined array of all years without duplicates.

My code is basic right now, but I'm constantly running into troubles.

```
function getDate () {
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            var dateSplit = elements.date[i].innerText.split('-'); 
            // this returns multiple arrays of {'year', 'month', 'day'}
            var dateOnly = dateSplit[0] // returns multiple strings of years
        }
}
```

How do i join dateOnly into one array?

Comment: Do you get multiple arrays or multiple array items ? There's a difference between the two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could collect the years in a `Set` and return an array of unique values.

```
function getDate() {
    const years = new Set;
    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        years.add(+elements.date[i].innerText.split('-', 1)[0]);
    }
    return [...years];
}
```

Comment: What does the `+` in `+elements.date[i]` do? Is that just string to number conversion?

Comment: @DBS it converts the string to Number

Comment: right it is an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) fo conversion to number.

Comment: @NinaScholz why you invoke Set without parenthesis?

Comment: @Randall, [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) calls the constructor/function and returns an instance. i need no parameter for an empty set. if you like to chain the instance, you need some braces.

Comment: Thanks a lot. [1 symbol]

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
function getYearAsArray(p1, p2) {
  var temp = ['2025-05-15', '2092-05-15', '2021-05-15', '2021-05-15'];
  
 var result =  temp.map(i=> {
  return i.replace(/^(\d{4})(-\d{2}-\d{2})$/, '$1');
  });
 
  return [...new Set(result)];;
}
```

[Check this](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GNWK9J48SFUD)